# Exact use cases of debounce in React

Tags: reactjs, onchange, debouncing

If an onChange event is invoked for each keyboard input and there is a logic inside the change handler that calls a particular API, we know that unnecessarily many calls are made, and we use **debounce** to resolve them.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  
  const registUser = (value) => {
    // particular API here
  };

  const debouncedOnChange = useCallback(debounce(registUser, 300), []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    debouncedOnChange(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I want to know. Should I use debounce if I simply set the status value in the change handler?

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  
  const onChange = (value) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const debouncedOnChange = useCallback(debounce(onChange, 300), []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    debouncedOnChange(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: no you dont need it, if you wanna do sth huge after state change it's better to use it to increase performance,otherwise it's not needed

Comment: it's mainly useful where we are doing some async actions like calling API, etc on every key press to prevent unnecessary polling and improve performance

Comment: Make your own debounce as lodash package is really big and that's not easy while loading.